# Oscillatory Integral

Tags: integral-transforms

Put $\eta = r+it, r>0$ and
$$K_{\eta}(z, w, \lambda)= \frac {\mid \lambda\mid }{2\sinh(\eta \mid \lambda \mid) }  e^{-\frac{\mid\lambda\mid \coth(\eta | \lambda |) \mid z-w \mid ^{2}}{4}} e^{-i \frac{\lambda}{2} Im(z\cdot \bar{w})}.$$
The Fourier transform in the last variable of the function $K_{\eta}(z, w, \lambda)$ is
$$\hat {K}_{\eta}(z, w)(\tau) = \int_{\mathbb R} K_{\eta}(z, w, \lambda) e^{-i\lambda \tau} d\lambda,\qquad z, w \in \mathbb C^{n}, \lambda \in \mathbb R.$$ 
Can we evaluate the integral $\hat {K}_{\eta}(z, w)(\tau)$, or can we say it is convergent, or can we get just estimate or would you like suggest some method to handle such oscillatory integral?

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a rather general answer, hopefully helping you to cope with your case. We consider
$$
I(\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{i\lambda\phi(x)}a(x,\lambda) dx,
$$
where $\lambda \ge 1$ is a real parameter (going to $+\infty$), $\phi$ is the phase,
a smooth complex-valued function such that $\Im \phi\ge 0,$
$$
\quad d\Re \phi=0 \text{  and } \Im\phi=0  \Longrightarrow \det(\phi'')\not=0.
\tag{$\natural$}
$$

The amplitude $a$ is in the Schwartz class (wrt the $x$ variable).
Then $I(\lambda)=O(\lambda^{-d/2})$ when $\lambda\rightarrow+\infty$.
If the phase depends also on $\lambda$, say if you replace $\lambda \phi(x)$ by $\lambda\Phi(x,\lambda)$, then you keep the assumption on $a$ but you also assume that 
 $\Phi$ is such that there exists 
positive constants
$c_0,C_0$ such that

$$
\quad d\Re \Phi=0 \text{  and } \Im\Phi=0  \Longrightarrow c_0\le \vert\det(\Phi'')\vert \le C_0.
\tag{$\sharp$}
$$
This is a short description of the method of complex stationary phase.

Note that the integral $I$ is largest at points where the phase is real-valued and stationary (i.e. with a vanishing gradient). This is quite natural after all since as long as the phase is positive you get an exponential decay, and when it is real-valued the differential of the imaginary part is also vanishing since that imaginary part is assumed to be non-negative. Then you must take a look at the Hessian of $\phi$, as in the method of real stationary phase for real-valued Morse function.